# How to set options?

Tags: angular, highcharts

After angular2 updated, they don't import Highcharts from angular2-highcharts anymore.
How can I set options? [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IuwjpPB1YQW1T7i4B8SZ?p=preview)

I want to add

```
Highcharts.setOptions({ lang: { thousandsSep: ',' } });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var require: any;
const Highcharts = require('highcharts');
Highcharts.setOptions({ lang: { thousandsSep: ',' } });

export class AppComponent {
...
```

Comment: Finally found an answer after hours of trial and error / hunting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the literal inside the constructor: (inside app/main.ts) in the plunker.

```
class AppComponent {
  constructor() { 
    this.options = {
      title : { text : 'simple chart' },
      series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129]
      }],
      lang: { thousandsSep: ',' }
    };
  }
  options: Object;
}
```